# Add private pod to podfile as dependency

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm working on pod which uses another private pod created by me and I need to add that pod somehow as a dependency in my podfile.

My podfile looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name             = 'test'
  spec.version          = '0.1'
  spec.license          = { :type => 'BSD' }
  spec.homepage         = 'http://www.test.com'
  spec.authors          = { 'test' => 'test@test.test' }
  spec.summary          = 'test module'
  spec.source           = { :git => 'https://bitbucket.org/test/test', :tag => spec.version.to_s }
  spec.source_files     = 'test'
  spec.requires_arc     = true
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  spec.platform = :ios, '8.0'

  spec.dependency 'SnapKit'

end
```

I tried adding as

```
spec.dependency 'Private pod'

spec.dependency 'Private pod' , :git => 'path-to-bitbucket-repo'
```

I looked for similar answers but nothing that was suggested works.

P.S. When i try:

```
pod spec lint DCCalendarMonth.podspec --sources=https://bitbucket.org/test/test.git,master
```

i get `The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.` --verbose tells me that:

```
ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (An unexpected version directory `Private pod subdirectory` was encountered for the `/Users/username/.cocoapods/repos/test/test` Pod in the `test` repository.) during validation.
```

I need some help or guidance because I'm getting little desperate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

inside spec.source field you just simply create field with multiple sources:

```
  spec.source           = { :git => 'https://bitbucket.org/decodehq/test1.git', :tag => spec.version.to_s , 
                            :git => 'https://bitbucket.org/decodehq/test2.git', :tag => spec.version.to_s
                          }
```

Comment: This is not working for me, because it will overwrite the first entry:
MySpec.podspec:24: warning: key :git is duplicated and overwritten on line 25
MySpec.podspec:24: warning: key :tag is duplicated and overwritten on line 25